# Find all natural numbers of the form $\overline{abcd}$ that verify a relation.

Tags: prime-numbers, contest-math

> Find all natural numbers of the form $\overline{abcd}$ that satisfy the relation $$\overline{abcd}=s(2s+d)^2$$ for which $s=a+b+c+d$ is a prime number.

**My idea.**

I don't think this is going to help that much but $1 \leq s \leq 36$. Because $s$ is prime $s=2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31$

I thought of analysing every case, but I think it will take too long.

I know that $2023$ is one of the numbers.

I also tried substituting $s$ with $a+b+c+d$ but it gets the equality to a much harder one.

Comment: This seems quite arbitrary...please edit to include the source of the problem.  Is there any particular reason to imagine that there's a better solution than a simple search?

Comment: @lulu It's from a math book from my country... i can tell you the source but its in country's language, not in english.

Comment: Well, a direct search is simple and fast, and reveals one other solution, namely $8112$.  I expect that there are ways to shorten the search...but I suspect that sorting those out takes a lot longer than brute force.

Comment: @lulu I understand...But I still think there must be a way to shorten the path because it wouldn't be put in that math book which is made for math contests...

Comment: @lulu Note that although $8112$ is a solution to $\overline{abcd}=s(2s+d)^2$, it's actually not a solution to the requested problem because a requirement is that $s=a+b+c+d$ be prime, but $8+1+1+2=12$ is not prime.

Comment: @JohnOmielan true, missed that rule.  And that rule speeds the search considerably... there are,  after all,  only 10 values of $d$ to check for each prime. Still slower than just running the mindless search though.

Comment: @lulu Actually, as I show in my answer, there are only at most $2$ values of $d$ that need to be checked for each prime. That's still a reasonable among of manual checking, but IMHO relatively doable.

Comment: Going forward, with your future MathSE postings, it would help if you provided pertinent definitions up front.  For example, it was not immediately clear to me that the expression $~\overline{abcd}~$ was supposed to represent $~1000a + 100b + 10c + d,~$ where $~a,b,c,d \in \{0,1,\cdots,9\},~$ and $~a \neq 0.~$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume the problem is only considering $4$ digit numbers, i.e., $a \ge 1$. If so then, for $s \le 5$, we have $s(2s + d)^2 \le 5\times (2\times 5 + 4)^2 = 980$, so none of them are possible. Thus, we only need to check $s \ge 7$.

The relation modulo $5$ gives that $d \neq 0, 5$. Next, using modulo $9$, since $\gcd(s, 9) = 1$, then

$$\overline{abcd}\equiv a + b + c + d \pmod{9} \;\to\; (2s + d)^2\equiv 1\pmod{9} \;\to\; 2s + d \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{9}$$

For $s = 7$, then $2s \equiv 5\pmod{9}$, so then $d$ must be either $3$ or $5$. With $d = 3$, we get $s(2s + d)^2 = 2023$, so it works, as you've already noted. However,  as stated earlier, $d = 5$ is not permitted.

With $s = 11$, then $2s \equiv 4\pmod{9}$, which means $d$ must be $4$ or $6$, resulting in $s(2s + d)^2$ being $7436$ or $8624$, with neither being valid.

One can go through the rest of the primes less than $36$ to confirm none of them work. One way to somewhat reduce the calculations is to take the product of the last digit of $s$ and the square of the last digit of $2s + d$. In most cases, the last digit of this would not be $d$.

There might be additional shortcuts, such as using other congruences, to moderately reduce the work, although determining and explaining them in an answer may actually involve more time & effort than what they save. Regardless, just what I've shown here makes the manual checking relatively doable since there are only at most $2$ values of $d$ which need to be investigated for each of the remaining primes $13 \le s \le 31$.

---

Update: As indicated in [Travis Willse's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4832154/find-all-natural-numbers-of-the-form-overlineabcd-that-verify-a-relation/4832218#comment10287379_4832218), and used in their [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4832307/602049), since $s \ge 17$ gives that $s(2s + d)^2 \ge 4\times 17^3 \gt 10^4$, we actually only need to check $s \le 13$. Since I've already checked here that $s \le 11$, the only additional check required is for $s = 13$.

Comment: If $s \geq 17$, then $s (2 s + d)^2 \geq 4 \cdot 17^3 > 10^4$, which contradicts that $s (2 s + d)^2$ is a $4$-digit number, hence the only case left to check is $s = 13$.

Comment: @TravisWillse Thanks for the feedback. I don't know how I missed that. I've updated my answer indicating that you commented & answered about that upper limit meaning there are not very many manual checks which are required.

Comment: @JohnOmielan For $s=13$ we have $d=2,0$ and the numbers we get $(10192 , 8788)$ cant be solutions. Am I right? Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @IONELABUCIU You're welcome. Regarding $s=13$, note that using modulo $9$ actually results in $d=2,0,9$ being the values to check. However, $d=0$ is not valid when checking modulo $5$, as I mentioned in my answer (since then $\overline{abcd}\equiv 0\pmod{5}$, but $s(2s+d)^2\equiv 4s^3\equiv 3\pmod{5}$). This elimination of $d=0$, so $d=9$ in those cases only remains, is why I stated there were at most $2$ values of $d$ to check for each value of $s$. Thus, for $d=2,9$, we instead get $(10192,15925)$, with neither being possible solutions.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** We'll assume that $a \neq 0$, so that $\overline{abcd}$ is a $4$-digit number, hence that $$10^3 \leq s (2 s + d)^2 < 10^4 .$$

If $s \leq 5$, then $d < s \leq 5$, hence
$$\overline{abcd} = s (2 s + d)^2 \leq 5 [2(5) + 4]^2 = 980,$$ a contradiction.

On the other hand,
$$4 s^3 \leq s (2 s + d)^2 < 10^4,$$
so $$s < 5 \cdot 20^{1/3} < 5 \cdot 27^{1/3} = 15 ,$$
and since $s$ prime we must have $s \in \{7, 11, 13\}$.

Notice that in any case, reducing modulo $9$ gives $$2 s + d \equiv \pm 1 \pmod 9,$$ so there are at most $3$ values of $d$ to check for each $s$, leaving at most $9$ possibilities $(s, d)$—in fact, there are just $7$.

> If $s = 7$, the condition modulo $9$ gives $d \in \{3, 5\}$, and $d = 3$ gives the solution $s (2 s + d)^2 = 7 \cdot 17^2 = \boxed{2023}$. Directly checking the $6$ other possibilities for $(s, d)$ gives no solutions.

**Remark** Suspending the restriction $a \neq 0$ gives one more solution, $0500$ ($s = 5$).